# autoit open firefox and activate addon

Tags: firefox, autoit

I am new AutoIT. I see it has a lot of potential.

How can I write autoit code to open FireFox from specific location and inside it activate addon. Then the autoit code would navigate to a link?

I have some examples but it has been less then 1 hour since I started working on autoit.

My goal is to change FireFox profiles, run links inside each of those and close Firefox.exe after some time...

Answer (score 0):

You can run the FireFox.exe to just bring the browser up [(here is the documentation on that)](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm) and there is a [FireFox AutoIt library available](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/167661-ffau3-v0601b-15/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below command to run your browser or any file

```
ShellExecute("filename")
```

or

```
Run( "The full path of the program f.ex- any exe or bat file")
```